# PayPal subscriptions and IPN

Tags: paypal

After a PayPal subscription is created for a user, does `subscr_signup` get sent before or after confirming the payment?

I am using [django-paypal](https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal), which does not have built-in functionality to handle the `subscr_payment` IPN message.

This lead me to wonder whether or not I can use `subscr_signup` as an indicator that the subscription was successful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically subscr_signup is sent after subscr_payment(3 sec apart), but the sequence is not guaranteed. PayPal recommendation is to rely on subscr_signup.
Read more here: http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/11/paypal-subscriptions-ipn-demystified/

Comment: Broken link - archive version here: http://web.archive.org/web/20190807215750/http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/11/paypal-subscriptions-ipn-demystified/